# Reduce PDF file size of plots by filtering hidden objects

Tags: r, pdf, vector, plot, ggplot2

While producing scatter plots of many points in R (using `ggplot()` for example), there might be many points that are behind the others and not visible at all. For instance see the plot below:

[image]

This is a scatter plot of several hundreds of thousands points, but most of them are behind the other points. The problem is when casting the output to a vector file (a PDF file for example), the invisible points make the file size so big, and increase memory and cpu usage while viewing the file.

A simple solution is to cast the output to a bitmap picture (TIFF or PNG for example), but they lose the vector quality and can be even larger in size. I tried some online PDF compressors, but the result was the same size as my original file.

Is there any good solution? For example some way to filter the points that are not visible, possibly during generating plot or after it by editing PDF file?

Comment: The recommended solution is a hexbin plot. However, in a hexbin plot colour indicates the number of values in each bin and you seem to use colour for something else.

Comment: +1 for hexbin. Other options are `sunflowerplot` and the `bigvis` package: https://github.com/hadley/bigvis

Comment: @Roland Yes, as you guessed the colors of points are meaningful, so for my case hexbin is not a good solution

Comment: If the colour has meaning, how would you like to handle points of different colour hiding behind each other? I don't think this is a good plot.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, but the plots you proposed are not suitable for my aim. I am happy with the current plot, but I just want to filter out the points behind others

Comment: @Roland There is a priority, for example the points with more extreme colors (light red or light green) are put on top. This works fine to have a global picture. Hidden invisible points are not important because of less fluctuations (black color)

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical that 'hidden' points are not important.  If that's really true, you should remove them from your analysis at some earlier point.   I tend to recommend using partial transparency for this sort of plot, e.g.  `color = #FF00FF44` so that you get an idea of the density of data points.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am comparing two different situations, the color means the alternation of any point within the two situations, and I have sorted the points according to the absolute alternation. So the zero alternation points are behind and invisible. Using transparency makes the file size and rendering time even worse.

Comment: That's my point:  remove the "zero alternation" data from your object before plotting it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Although many of zero alternation points are hidden behind other points, they are needed to show the global trend of data. please see the picture above: there are many black points that shape the chart. I think Roland solution below is one of the best

Comment: See also (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222764/how-to-rasterize-a-single-layer-of-a-ggplot)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a start you can do something like this:

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(x=x<-runif(1e6),y=x+rnorm(1e6,sd=0.1))
plot(y~x,data=DF,pch=".",cex=4)
```

[image]

PDF size: 6334 KB

```
DF2 <- data.frame(x=round(DF$x,3),y=round(DF$y,3))
DF2 <- DF[!duplicated(DF2),]
nrow(DF2)
#[1] 373429
plot(y~x,data=DF2,pch=".",cex=4)
```

[image]

PDF size: 2373 KB

With the rounding you can control how many values you want to remove. You only need to modify this to handle the different colours.

Comment: We may first divide the X and Y values to the minimum horizontal/vertical distance we desire between the points, round it and then filter out duplicates: `temp <- round(DF2 / .1); DF2 <- DF2[!duplicated(temp),]`

Comment: +1 for the great idea of rounding! This was extremely great solution, reduced my PDF size considerably. Thank a lot

Answer (score 4):

Simply saving the plot as a high-res `png` file will very drastically cut the size, while keeping the quality more than good enough. At least I've never had journals complain about any of the png's I sent them, just keep sure to use > 600 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be done with some post-processing of the pdf-file. In linux, if I have to reduce a pdf, I would do

```
pdf2ps input.pdf output.ps
ps2pdf output.ps output.pdf
```

which for some reason works quite efficiently.

You can see some discussion at https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-to-reduce-pdf-filesize.

Comment: Thanks, but they are exactly the same size, possibly because the initial PDF file is a vector and not bitmap file. I tried several solutions of your ask-ubuntu link.