# writing png plots into a pdf file in R

Tags: r, pdf, plot, png, graphic

I have to create a bunch of graphs with a lot of data points. So far, I've been doing this by plotting all of them into one `pdf`-file:

```
pdf("testgraph.pdf")  
par(mfrow=c(3,3))

for (i in 2:length(names(mtcars))){
  plot(mtcars[,1], mtcars[,i])
}

dev.off()
```

However, with a lot of data points the `pdf` file becomes too large. As I'm not interested in outstanding quality, I don't care if my plots are vector graphics or not. So I thought of creating the plots as `png` and subsequently inserting them into a `pdf` file. Is there a way to do this except of creating `R` graphs and inserting them into `pdf` with `knitr` (which I think is too tedious for such a simple job)?

Comment: I wrote some code [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059) that might be of interest.

Comment: If you used ggplot, there was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222764/how-to-rasterize-a-single-layer-of-a-ggplot).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can

1. create .png files of each plot
2. use the `png` package to read those back in and
3. plot them in a pdf using `grid.arrange`

```
library(png)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

thePlots <- lapply (2:length(names(mtcars)), function(i) {
  png("testgraph.png")
  plot(mtcars[,1], mtcars[,i])

  dev.off()
  rasterGrob(readPNG("testgraph.png", native = FALSE),
    interpolate = FALSE)
})

pdf("testgraph.pdf")
do.call(grid.arrange, c(thePlots, ncol = 3))
dev.off()
```

Comment: For some reason the `library(png)` line kills the formatting for the rest of the post...

Comment: Great, thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to do! However, I'm surprised that in fact the resulting `pdf` files got even larger... Wouldn't have thought that. I guess I'll have to look into the other options to decrease plot size that have been suggested here.

Comment: @BenBarnes: The formatting problem you had is described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item).

Comment: I used this technique for plotting multiple maps, in which case the resulting pdf was much smaller than plotting directly to pdf. In your case, reducing the data complexity prior to plotting sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

If the source of the problem is too many points in the plot then you might want to consider using hexagonal binning instead of a regular scatterplot.  You can use the hexbin package from bioconductor or the ggplot2 package has hexagonal binning capabilities as well.  Either way you will probably get a more meaningful plot as well as smaller file size when creating a pdf file directly.

Comment: You're right, this might be another option, thanks! I'll have to try out the suggestions here to find the best way for my data.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the PNG files to PDF with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

```
for i in *.png
do
  convert "$i" "$i".pdf
done
```

and concatenate the resulting files with [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/).

```
pdftk *.png.pdf output all.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to stick to `R` without using any additional software.