# How to save a pdf in R with a lot of points

Tags: r, pdf, plot

So I have to save a pdf plot with a lot of points in it. That is not a problem. The problem is that when I open it. It takes forever to plot all those points.  How can I save this pdf in such a way that it doesn't have to draw point by point when someone opens it. I'm OK if the quality of the picture goes down a bit.

Here's a sample. I don't think this would crash your computer but be careful with the parameter length if you have an old machine. I am using many more points than that in my real problem by the way.

```
pdf("lots of points.pdf")
x <- seq(0,100, length = 100000)
y <- 0.00001 * x
plot(x, y)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Um....only plot _some_ of your points, or only plot summaries of your data?

Comment: if you don't absolutely insist on a PDF, you can just make an insanely high-resolution PNG -- it won't be much bigger, due to the compression, and it will be effectively the same resolution as a vector-based PDF on any display smaller than a billboard ...

Comment: Good one. @BenBolker. But it has to be a PDF.

Comment: one quick trick is to use `pch="."`

Comment: you could convert the PNG to PDF, if you're on *nix, use imagemagick (command line tools). Here's a link on quality issues with pdf from PNG http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42856/how-can-i-convert-a-png-to-a-pdf-in-high-quality-so-its-not-blurry-or-fuzzy

Comment: imagemagick is cross-platform: http://www.imagemagick.org/ , http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php

Comment: If you're on a Mac, just open the png file in Preview, then open the print dialogue and use the PDF menu at the bottom-left corner to save it as a PDF.

Comment: you can export the data points only as a png, reimport this into R, and draw it with axes etc. using rasterImage. The tricky part is to make sure the axes are well aligned with the image layer.

Comment: For my particular problem pch="." does the trick :) @BenBolker

Comment: @WilmerHenao , perhaps describe what you did and post it as an answer (e.g. compare file sizes/approximate times to display the PDF in an external viewer)?

Comment: Nothing. I just added the pch="." parameter to my plots (there are 3 plots on each page).  Now every page takes a fraction of a second to open. Before this, it was taking roughly 12 seconds.  Hard to measure but I estimate it's a 25 times improvement.  Also the size of the file is reduced by roughly 10%

Comment: And quite frankly it looks more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: You could sample down your number of points or avoid plotting hidden points like I show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059).

Comment: Hey @Roland . That's a really good solution too. I went ahead and implemented the !duplicated . It effectively reduced the size of my file by roughly half without any loss of quality.

The time was already a non-issue, but I'm sure it's opening faster too.

Comment: @Roland . Today I'm having a similar problem. I'm using this function pairs.panels from the package psych. I think the creators of those packages could steal your techniques :)

Anyway, I guess my solution is to not use them. But the graphs are really cool.  But slow...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and there is a sound solution. The drawback is that this solution is not generic and does not involve programming (always bad).

For draft purposes, png or any other graphic format may be sufficient, but for presentation purposes this is often not the case. So the way to go is to combine vector graphics for fonts, axis etc and bitmap for your zillions of points:

1) save as pdf (huge and nasty)

2) load into illustrator or likewise ( must have layers )

3) separate  points from all other stuff by dragging other stuff to new layer - save as A

4) delete other stuff and export points only as bitmap (png, jpg) and save as B

5) load B into A; scale and move B to exact overlap; delete vector points layer, and export as slender pdf.

done. takes you 30 minutes.

As said this has nothing to do with programming, but there is simply no way around the fact that as vector graphics each and every point (even those that are not visible, since covered by others) are single elements and its a pain handling pdfs with thousands of elements.
So there is need for postprocessing. I know ImageMagick can do alot, but AFAIK the above cant be done by an algorithm.

The only programming way to (partly) solve this is to eliminate those points that will not display because the are covered by others. But thats beyond me.

Only go this way if you really and desperately need extreme scalability, otherwise go with @Ben and @inform and use a bitmap --in whatever container you need it (png,pdf,bmp,jpg,tif, even eps).