# Optimize ggplot to vectorial graphical device

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

Let's say I want to save all my charts (for font and axis style consistency) via a vectorial graphical device (such as `pdf()`).

Yet sometime some graph is overly complicated - although still visually acceptable - consisting of many overlapping objects, which create a heavy vectorial image that might create problems when embedded in a PDF document (very slow rendering).

I am wonder if it is possible to have `ggplot` to simplify a `geom_point` still maintaining  the same aspect before sending it to a graphical device. (Yes, I know I could drop altogether plotting points and plot - for example - a heatmap or a binhex...)

For example this MWE plot 5000 datapoints

```
library(ggplot2)

pdf("SampleGraph.pdf",width=7,height=5)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5000), y = rnorm(5000))
ggplot (df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(size=5, alpha=.5)
dev.off()
```

and the resulting `SampleGraph.pdf`is 300kb but even with alpha=.5 most of the points are totally obscured by others.

Comment: Just to mention, although it is not really relevant for your question: The usual way to save `ggplot` objects is via `?ggsave`.

Comment: Other than dropping points, I don't see how one could make the pdf lighter. Would love to be shown wrong, though.

Comment: Have a look at this answer by me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059 Does it provide what you need? Then we could close this question as a duplicate.