# Why do saved pdfs of R graphics slow down my computer?

Tags: r

When I try to open a pdf of a graphic I created in R, my computer slows down. I am having difficulty adding them to presentations and reports. It is only certain graphics, which took a long time (3hrs) to create. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Probably because they are loading thousands (millions?) of individual lines/points. Plot less points or save your plots to png first --> process to pdf.

Comment: If you are on linux you ca use `convert` to make them png.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In order for us to give you a sensible answer, you need to provide a reproducible example (with code) of a plot like the one you made. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You probably should make a hexbin plot or do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059