# Efficiently plotting millions of data points in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some million data points in R. I'm currently using ggplot2 (but I'm open to suggestions of alternate packages). The problem is that the graph takes too long to render (often upwards of a minute). I'm looking for ways to do this faster -- in real time ideally. I would appreciate any help -- attaching code to the question for clarity.

Creating a (random) data frame with ~500000 data points:

```
letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
myLetters <- sample(x = letters, size = 100000, replace = T)
direction <- c("x", "y", "z")
factor1 <- sample(x = direction, size = 100000, replace = T)
factor2 <- runif(100000, 0, 20)
factor3 <- runif(100000, 0, 100)
decile <- sample(x = 1:10, size = 100000, replace = T)


new.plot.df <- data.frame(letters = myLetters, factor1 = factor1, factor2 = factor2, 
                      factor3 = factor3, decile = decile)
```

Now, plotting the data:

```
color.plot <- ggplot(new.plot.df, aes(x = factor3, y = factor2, color = factor1)) +
geom_point(aes(alpha = factor2)) +
facet_grid(decile ~ letters)
```

[image]

**How do I make the rendering faster?**

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind would be taking a subset of the full data you are plotting.  Fewer points should presumably mean faster rendering times.  The trick is to figure out how to sample the millions of points.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am trying different sampling methods, but apart from going down that route, is there another way?

Comment: The only 2 things which might be an alternative would be to somehow manpulate `ggplot` to render faster, which would require expertise which I do not have.  And the other possibility would be of course to get a faster machine, which probably isn't an option.

Comment: Well, if you're willing to experiment, `ggvis` is similar to `ggplot2`, and one could call it `ggplot` child. You may try to use it for visualization and see if it is faster

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux is there a way to create panels in ggvis? I'm not able to find the ggvis equivalent of facet_grid.

Comment: hum...gvis is much slower than ggplot2 with big data.

Comment: You should reconsider the plot. There is probably a better approach for visualizing your data. Anyway, here is an answer that demonstrates how to subset data so that only points with sufficiently different coordinates are plotted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059

Comment: @KaranTibrewal quickly looked at released version of ggvis, there are no facets as of v0.4. It is in the works and should be here shortly. Thus, I withdraw my suggestion. Wrt speed, I would say ggvis clearly faster on updates, no questions about it. And in ggvis you could with simple control make partial data plot, while making optional full plot

Comment: @KaranTibrewal please check http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117078/for-plotting-with-r-should-i-learn-ggplot2-or-ggvis, answered by Bob. This is pretty much correlates with my experience wrt speed

Comment: You may check the bigvis package. See [here](https://github.com/hadley/bigvis) and [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/bigvis.pdf).

Comment: Use the `'.'` symbol. You'll lose some visualization capabilities though.

Answer (score 20):

There are two main sources of slowness in R plotting:

1. graphics device and backend in general
2. plotting too much of complicated shapes

Graphical back-end can be altered using appropriate device-opening and backend-selection commands -- for me, this usually helps:

```
options(bitmapType='cairo')  #set the drawing backend, this may speed up PNG rendering
x11(type='cairo')   #drawing to X11 window using cairo is the fastest interactive output for me
```

(X11 is not available on windows and a little confusing in Rstudio, but that's a different story)

Plotting simpler shapes helps quite a lot. ggplot uses some variant of `pch=19` or `pch=20` by default, which are way too slow because of anti-aliasing. You can usually get about 10x faster rendering by using `pch='.'` (which is just a single non-aliased pixel) or `pch=16` (which is a small non-aliased circle). That also applies for ggplot with `shape='.'` and `shape=16`, respectively. If you have a lot of points and set appropriately lower alpha, you'll get the "anti-aliasing" for free.

For me, just switching the graphical backend and setting different point shape improved drawing of 1 million points from around 30 minutes to seconds. 500k data points should be rendered in under a second.

*EDIT* (Jan 2020): I recently made a library that speeds this up even more: https://github.com/exaexa/scattermore

Comment: Thanks for the library! It's been helping a lot.

Answer (score 4):

In general there are two strategies that I use for this:

1) As described in the comments, taking a reasonable descriptive sample of your data is not going to affect your plot and you will reduce the number of points to render.

2) One trick that I use is actually to create the object without displaying the plot and instead save the plot into a PNG image. This actually speeds up the process by a lot because when you open the image it's going to be a raster rather than a vectorial image.