# Writing printer friendly pdfs with ggplot2 and many (>25000) dots or lines

Tags: r, pdf, printing, ggplot2

I am creating a lot of facet plots with `ggplot2` and writing those into a multiple page pdf file. I added some sample data as an example.

```
reps <- 1000
df <- data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:25], each=reps),
                 group=rep(LETTERS[1:25], each=reps),
                 x=runif(reps*25),
                 y=runif(reps*25))
pdf('test.pdf', width=11.69, height=8.27)
for(i in seq(4)) {
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group=group)) +
    geom_line() + geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ id)
  print(p)
}
dev.off()
```

To view the PDF it is really nice, but most of the time these big files with vector graphics kill my print jobs.

Is there a way to handle this properly? For example, creating PNG images and saving them in multipage PDFs? Or, am I the only one having problems printing such files?

I am aware that the PNG file might be bigger, but I guess the printer can handle it much better than a vector graphic.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059) is relevant? Often problems like this are a hint that you should redesign your plot, e.g., consider a hexbin plot.

Comment: @Roland actually, I have line graphs with 20 timepoints and 100 lines per graph. I use `facet_wrap` to highlight individual lines with a background of 99 lines :-) I don't think there is a a way to redesign a lot here. Actually I already plot only the line and no points. The PDF has in the End 8 pages with 12 facets per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is the following: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/quick-fix-print-pdf-image.html

I think this might be the best way since the creation of PDF is the same, you just switch to "print as image" in the advance printing dialog in Acrobat Reader...