# Base-R scatter plot with 800K points becomes untractable in PDF - rasterizing options?

Tags: r, pdf, graphics, vector-graphics, rasterizing

For a publication, I need to provide a vectorized graphic. I want to plot data and show an approximation at a certain range. To have full control over approximation scope and calculation, I did it in base R. For export, I use R's built-in `pdf` device. The code in a nutshell is

```
    pdf(file = paste0(pdf_outFile, ".pdf"), onefile = TRUE, paper="a4r") 

    plot(...)  # light blue              
    points(...)  # grey
    points(...)  # dark blue

    # mark smoothed opt (combined of two fitted curves)
    points()  # light blue
    points()  # grey
    points()  # dark blue

    # highlight optimum        
    abline(v=optX, ...)
    abline(h=optY, ...)
    points(optX, optY, ...),
    dev.off()
```

[image: Example image]

I have about 800K single points in this data and this crashes Adobe PDF, even though the PDF itself has only a size of 13 MB. When opening it, all points are written one after another and it looks like an animation. The publisher does not accept this pdf. I also tried exporting the layers one after another to different pdf s but even then it crashed Adobe PDF.

Is there a way to partially raster the image to make have less points and a better user experience with PDF readers? For ggplot2 there seems to be a new package called [ggrastr](https://github.com/VPetukhov/ggrastr) dealing with this but I would like to use my solution with base R. Is there maybe some other device giving vector graphics where you can rasterize layers?

Comment: Output as jpeg, then add the image to pdf? Or output as SVG?

Comment: The actual answer is probably that you should make a different plot (e.g., a hexbin plot can be useful if you have strong over-plotting), but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665420/reduce-pdf-file-size-of-plots-by-filtering-hidden-objects/16668596#16668596

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and decided to reshape my data in a way that I can just plot them with `ggplot2` and `ggrastr`. This yielded the desired result.