# How to draw millions of lines fast

Tags: r, ggplot2

x axes could be treated as 1:n.

y axes values distribute in a limited range [-1, 1]

I want to draw line segments connecting all points described by vectors above

```
geom_line(aes(x, y))
```

All works good except for the performance. It takes minutes to render the final image. Sample plot goes blow.

[image: Sample plot]

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Thank you for your comments. I did tried a resampling. But it's very hard to me to do a real "smart" resampling. As we cares a lot about the "out of local mean values" which is usually considered as "noise" in many statistical cases. Please allow me to show the problem by image, though it's not encouraged.

[image]

The image above is the original one, while below is the resampled one. I market the "important" information loss with arrows in the original image.

Comment: If I understand your case correctly, for this specific case perhaps you could instead use `geom_ribbon` just to plot the whole thing instead of many lines?

Comment: do you need to draw all the points?

Comment: ggplot2 produces better image but lines() is also acceptable. but... I don't see significant improvement if switch to lines()...

Comment: I don't have to draw all points but I have to preserve details on the edge. So rebbon is also not good enough...

Comment: You should definitely avoid plotting millions of lines. That can't be fast and they are plotted on top of each other anyway. You should plot a "smart" subsample. For points I have shown an approach in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668596/1412059

Comment: Roland's advice is good. You don't have millions of pixels, so plotting millions of lines is wasted. Smart sampling is one approach. Or you could do one segment from ymin to ymax for each x - only draw `n` lines. If you want answers with code **please share some sample data**. For data like this, maybe just `set.seed` and share some code to simulate sample data so we can all have a good example to work with.

Comment: It's very hard to do a "smart resampling" to me. As we cares about the "out of local mean values". To avoid too many comments I edited the original post. Thanks a lot for all the comments.

Comment: I think you'll find the solution by asking the right question, you obviously don't need a million line because you won't be looking at a million things. From what I'm gathering sampling is not satisfying because you're losing some singular values, so maybe what you want to do is single those out ? maybe you need the min and the max for given time intervals ? or rolling mins / rolling maxes ? Or you want to spot outliers that jump more than a given delta from a rolling average ?

Comment: The latter might be what you mean by ""out of local mean values", so maybe you can plot this local mean as a line, and these important outliers as points ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for commenting so much. Eventually I think I could resolve this by aggregating hundreds of values into one line range.

To be more descriptive, assume there're 1M points.

1. Group them into 10K groups, with 100 points in each group.
2. Get the min & max values of each group.
3. For each group, draw a vertical line from min to max.

By doing such aggregation I could reduce the data by 1/group.size

Still, it surprises me a little that drawing one line could take tens of microseconds in R. At the very beginning I was thinking if there's any solution like "hardware acceleration"

Comment: By the way, is there any way to mark this question as "resolved"? Or I don't need to do this in stackoverflow?

Comment: You can "accept" the answer to mark the question resolved. SInce you answered your own question there is a 24 hour waiting period before you can accept.

Comment: As to your comment about "it surprises me a little that drawing one line could take tens of microseconds", it's not *just* drawing a line, itt's figuring out where to draw it. This is complicated when you provide many times more points/lines than there are pixels.