# Efficient way to produce a 10x10 plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've written the following piece of code to produce a 10x10 plot in a Shiny R application. I perform some additional calculations (e.g. estimation of the R square) which makes the process even a bit heavier/slower, but I believe there is an entirely different and more efficient way to create the following plot rather than iterating using nested `for` loops.

```
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow=c(10,10))
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)+0.1)
    for (i in 0:9){
      for (j in 0:9){
        plot(df()[,c(paste0("intensity_",i), paste0("intensity_",j))], xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, main=NULL, yaxt='n',xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
        abline(fit <- lm(df()[,c(paste0("intensity_",i), paste0("intensity_",j))], data=df()), col='red')
        legend("topleft", bty="n", legend=format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3))
      }
    }
})
```

The code above produces the following figure:
[image]

Could you please advice whether there is a better alternative way of doing that which would produce the same output in a more R-friendly way and in a shorter period of time?

*The df() has 10 columns and thousands of numerical records

Comment: You could use ggplot2 with faceting but your main problem is probably the sheer  number of points you are plotting. You could try removing points that are invisible due to over-plotting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665420/reduce-pdf-file-size-of-plots-by-filtering-hidden-objects/16668596#16668596

Comment: Having a snippet of data to run your function and make couple of test would he really helpful. I suspect something can be done by using the `lapply` family. Being vectorized it should run faster.

Comment: @AndreaDodet `lapply` is not vectorized and certainly not faster, possibly even slower if you don't need return values but only a side effect (like plotting). But I'd expect most time is spent in the `plot` function anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like pairs, so half of your plot is repeated, so for the lower half, I place the rsquare values:

```
# Rsq for panel
panel.rsq <- function(x, y){
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
    r <- cor(x, y)
    txt <- paste0("R^2 = ", round(r^2,digits=2))
    cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
    text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}
# Customize upper panel
upper.panel<-function(x, y){
  points(x,y, pch = 19)
  abline(lm(y~x),col="red")
}


df = data.frame(replicate(10,1:100)+replicate(10,rnorm(100,20,5)))
pairs(df, 
      lower.panel = panel.rsq,
      upper.panel = upper.panel)
```

[image]

If this is still too slow, you might have to use lattice...

Comment: Nice idea, hadn't think of something like this, I'll give it a try